# Group by multiple columns with different row values

Tags: mysql

I have a table which consists of messages going from user a to user b (and more users) or vice versa.

I am trying to retrieve the last message from any conversation between users, additionally I want to order it by messagetime descending.

My table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| userid | touserid | messsagetime  |     message      |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------+
|      1 |        2 | 1504637613197 | hello            |
|      1 |        2 | 1504637938942 | how are you?     |
|      2 |        1 | 1504637970246 | i'm fine thanks. |
|      3 |        1 | 1504640245930 | hello            |
|      1 |        3 | 1504640322756 | hello!           |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------+
| userid | touserid | messsagetime  |     message      |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------+
|      2 |        1 | 1504637970246 | i'm fine thanks. |
|      1 |        3 | 1504640322756 | hello!           |
+--------+----------+---------------+------------------+`
```

Unfortunately, my MySQL knowledge is limited and this is as far as I got:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM messages 
        WHERE userid = 1  
           or touserid = 1
        ORDER 
            BY messagetime desc
     ) AS a 
 GROUP 
    BY userid
```

Which does order it by messagetime and just 1 message for `from` - `to` but won't group the messages together that came from the other user.

Create / Insert for sample data:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,   `touser` int(11) NOT NULL,   `fromuser` int(11) NOT
 NULL,   `messagetime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,   `message` text COLLATE
 utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


 INSERT INTO `1` (`id`, `touser`, `fromuser`, `messagetime`, `message`)
 VALUES (1, 1, 2, 1504637613197, 'hello'), (2, 1, 2, 1504637938942,
 'how are you? '), (3, 2, 1, 1504637970246, 'i''m fine thanks.'), (4,
 3, 1, 1504640245930, 'hello'), (5, 1, 3, 1504640322756, 'hello!');
```

Is there any MySQL wizardry that will achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Providing create and insert statements will be helpful to solve it faster for someone here

Comment: What is supposed to happen to the last messages from user1 to user2?

Comment: @RiggsFolly they shouldn't be returned at all since the message from user2 to user1 has been sent at a later time.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan added to original question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a faster way but this is my first pass:
http://rextester.com/FCQU57469

We use a union to switch the touserid and fromuserId so we can identify "conversations" between two people.  We then simply get the max timestamp for each pairing.  We then join this back to a base set on time and userID being in one or the other. It's this part that could be slow.  it should be noted if user A and B had conversations on different days or years... that only the latest between the two would be returned.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT max(messageTime) mmt, A, B
      FROM (SELECT touser A, fromuser B, messageTime 
            FROM SO46062696
            UNION ALL
            SELECT fromuser A, touser B, messageTime 
            FROM SO46062696) Z
      WHERE  A < B   
      GROUP BY A,B
     ) Y
INNER JOIN SO46062696 x
 on Y.mmt = x.messagetime
and Y.A in (x.touser, x.fromuser)
and Y.B in (x.touser, x.fromuser)
```

The lines having a # below could be places to put the touser = 1.

- The Z subset must have it on both statement before the union.  This to me is the ideal place for performance but I'm not sure it gives the results you're after as it only looks at Touser1.
- But maybe you mean where FromUser = 1 or touser=1 in which case while it may be ideal it needs to be placed after the union in set Y's where clause.  Both illustrated below.

This example: http://rextester.com/CFO21487 shows the where `A < B and Z.a=1`
it is what I think you're after; all conversations in which userId 1 partook (to or from) and their most recent conversation of each with a unique partner.  In this case think of a as the USERId below, without a from or to reference.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT max(messageTime) mmt, A, B
      FROM (SELECT touser A, fromuser B, messageTime 
            FROM SO46062696
            #WHERE touser = 1  #Prefered1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT fromuser A, touser B, messageTime 
            FROM SO46062696
            #WHERE touser=1  #Prefered1) Z
      WHERE  A < B   
      #  and Z.A = 1  #added Less Optimal
      GROUP BY A,B
     ) Y

INNER JOIN SO46062696 x
 on Y.mmt = x.messagetime
and Y.A in (x.touser, x.fromuser)
and Y.B in (x.touser, x.fromuser)
```

There may yet be a more optimal way; but I need to understand what you mean by userID 1 as userID isn't a column in your data set.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'm not quite sure where does the `WHERE` statement go in your query. Let's say for `userId = '1'`?

Comment: Updated to provide two places inside the Z subset is best but it must go on both selects.  Also added a rextester example so you can play with it.  However that may not give you the desired results I'm not sure what you mean by userID = 1 so it may be better after the where A<B using an and both illustrated above with a # preceeding the line

Comment: Note my alias could be cleaner. I was in a hurry and didn't consider good names, you may want to revisit A,B, x, y, Z and name better for clarity.